# How to use composition with pandas DataFrame and Series rather than inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, pandas, composition

I am very tempted to inheritance and subclass a pandas `DataFrame` for my use case, but from everything I've read about [good programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and the [Pandas internals documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html) this is not the right thing to do.

As a simplified example lets say the rows of my `DataFrame` are people and the fields are height and weight.  I'm tempted to subclass so that I can have a method which is `bmi()`.  I would do this as follows:

import pandas as pd

```
class People(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(People, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def bmi(self):
        return self['weight'] / self['height'] ** 2 x 703

people = People([[172, 74], [100, 60]])
bmi = people.bmi()
```

How would I do this using composition?  Would it be something like:

```
class People(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = pd.DataFrame(data)

    def bmi(self):
        return self.data['weight'] / self.data['height'] ** 2 x 703

people = People([[172, 74], [100, 60]])
bmi = people.bmi()
```

If not, how would I do it?  If so, why is this better?

Note: I realize this is an oversimplified example.

Comment: My apologies if I'm over simplifying but if your goal is to create field in data set with bmi (or other calculated field) there are much easier alternatives (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#basics-pipe)

Comment: @lovemySO Thanks, I did see that.  My actual problem is quite a bit more complicated in that it has many more fields and methods.  So I guess ultimately my question is really about how/when to use inheritance and composition and how I would do that in a concrete example with pandas DataFrames.

Comment: I think the answer to you question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504756/pandas-dataframe-object-inheritance-or-object-use

Comment: @Gillu13 Yeah good call.  Composition is definitely the way to go with this I think.