# Calling set_index() in __init__() with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a custom class that inherits from pandas.DataFrame. Here is how the code looks like:

```
class ABC(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        pd.DataFrame.__init__(self, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
        self.set_index(['a', 'b'])

c = ABC()
In [7]: c
Out[7]:
Empty ABC
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

The index doesn't get set if I try to set a multiindex in **init**(). This is the same if I use single index. Any idea how to set the index as the object is created? This is preferred over separating the index as a separate series and setting index=index_series as the data comes in as a whole block

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that a lot of methods in DataFrame returns a new instance of itself. So it's better to code it as composition rather than inheritance.

[Pandas DataFrame Object Inheritance or Object Use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504756/pandas-dataframe-object-inheritance-or-object-use)