# pandas set_index in class initialization doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a class that takes care of the data loading.

This creates an object containing dataframes, pandas series and matrices in a class-like structure:

```
data.
     my_df_object
     my_matrix_object
     my_series_object
```

I feed `data` to another class (say `class_do_stuff`) that needs to do stuff with the data.

```
import pandas as pd

def __init__(self, data):
        self.dynamic_data = copy.deepcopy(data) # create a copy of the data to avoid unwanted
        # Need to add a multilayer index to one of the objects for easier handling.
        # tried both the following solutions and none work
        self.dynamic_data.my_df_object.set_index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], inplace = True)
        self.dynamic_data.my_df_object = self.dynamic_data.my_df_object.set_index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
```

Unfortunately none of the last two lines work as they both returns a dataframe like:

```
In: class_do_stuff.dynamic_data.my_df_object.index
Out: Int64Index([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7],
           dtype='int64', length=8)

In: class_do_stuff.dynamic_data.my_df_object.columns
Out: Index(['Col4', 'Col5'], dtype='object')
```

Now, I know the syntax is correct as both lines work if ran outside of the class initialization.

So the question is, am I doing something wrong? How can I fix it?

Sample dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_df_object = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Col1':[1,1,2,3,3,4,8,10],
    'Col2':[10,3,5,6,6,3,5,9],
    'Col3':[1,2,4,3,5,2,1,6],
    'Col4':np.random.randn(8),
    'Col5':np.random.randint(1,8,8),
    })
```

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24506237/3284713) but I am not even sure if it relates to my case and what the actual suggested solution is.

**UPDATE**

Creating a new object works fine:

```
import pandas as pd

def __init__(self, data):
        self.dynamic_data = copy.deepcopy(data) # create a copy of the data to avoid unwanted
        # Need to add a multilayer index to one of the objects for easier handling.
        self.dynamic_data.my_new_df_object = self.dynamic_data.my_df_object.set_index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
```

This is of course a suboptimal solution and I still can't understand why this is happening.

**UPDATE 2**

None of the two following approaches work

```
import pandas as pd

def __init__(self, data):
        self.dynamic_data = copy.deepcopy(data) # create a copy of the data to avoid unwanted
        # Need to add a multilayer index to one of the objects for easier handling.
        tmp = self.dynamic_data.my_df_object.set_index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
        self.dynamic_data.my_df_object = tmp.copy()
        del tmp
```

```
import pandas as pd

def __init__(self, data):
        self.dynamic_data = copy.deepcopy(data) # create a copy of the data to avoid unwanted
        # Need to add a multilayer index to one of the objects for easier handling.
        tmp = self.dynamic_data.my_df_object.set_index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
        del self.dynamic_data.my_df_object
        self.dynamic_data.my_df_object = tmp.copy()
        del tmp
```